# Embed Silverlight app in a jsp portlet

Tags: silverlight, portlet

How to embed a silverlight app in a jsp portlet?
Rgds

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the structure of portlets, but since Silverlight is a client technology, anywhere the portlet is delivering HTML content, you would just put your  tag for Silverlight and your app.